# Taylor series odd conclusion

Tags: taylor-expansion

I write down the Taylor (Mclaurin) expansion of the analytic function f:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{k} \frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\bigg|_{x=0} (f(x))
\end{equation}

It is easy to show that 
\begin{equation}
\hat{A}=x\frac{d}{dx}
\end{equation}
is linear, therefore also
\begin{equation}
\hat{A^k}=x^k\frac{d^k}{dx^k}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k} \frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\bigg|_{x=0}
\end{equation}
are linear too.
I then conclude that
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \lbrace\sum_{k} \frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\bigg|_{x=0}\rbrace f(x)\\
f(x) = exp (\hat{A}) f(x)\\
exp (\hat{A}) = exp (x\frac{d}{dx}) = 1 = exp (0) = exp (2\pi i)
\end{equation}

I consider now the equation
\begin{equation}
x\frac{d}{dx} = 2\pi i
\end{equation}
is it totally wrong? why? 
are there some weaker assumption that could be made in order to make sense to the whole thing?

Comment: You wrote something similar to $f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\Rightarrow\frac{d}{dx}=1$ what do you think of it ?

Comment: So, where is the mistake?

Comment: your first equation is not true for every function, mine is true for every analytic one.
there's a little difference, don't you think?

Comment: $\exp(\hat A)$ is an operator or to speak simply a function. You cannot simplify things like $T(f(x))=f(x)$ to say $T=id$ and you did worse, you said $1$ a scaler instead of identity operator. What you really want is to find the eigenvalues of $T$.

Comment: which is the identity in R^1 ?

Comment: 'f' is not the 'unknown', exp(A) is, unlike the differential equation you wrote, where is to find 'f'.
my hp is that f is every analytic function, I don't have to find it.
and if T(x) = x for every x then T=id, no?

Comment: $A^2(f)=A(Af)=x(Af)'=x(xf')'=x(xf''+f')=x^2f''+xf'$ is not generally equal to $x^2d^2f/dx^2=x^2f''$.

Comment: I get it now, thank you